# Converting existing android application which is developed in 240 density toe 320 density

Tags: android

If we want to convert our existing android applications developed in 240 density (1024x600) to 320 (1024x600) density, do I need to change the entire Layout UI files of the current application or do we have any other alternatives. Can we apply 320 density programetically to the current 240 density application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No just change any bitmaps to have an xhdpi form.  The whole point of density changes is that the layout doesn't change, because everything is scaled with the density.  That is why you use "dp" units in your layout.

Comment: So, by just adding the images that fits in 320 dp in xhdpi folder is enough and everything can be left as it is, right? If the device set to 320 dp then it automatically calls the images in xhdpi folder, right? please clarify..

Comment: Here in my 240 density layouts  I have used everything in dp's and sp's for text, so I hope just by saving the images in xhdpi for 320dpi works fine, right?

Comment: How can I test or know whether the images under drawable-xhdpi is loading when we set emulator to 320dp? One more doubt whether android 2.2 support for xhdpi ? please help...

Comment: Use just add xhdpi drawables.  The xhdpi density was added in I believe 2.2.  It doesn't matter.  Run an AVD with the current GB emulator set up as an xhdpi device.

Comment: Here in Android 2.2 API 8 version, if we create a folder with name drawable-xhdpi and placing all the files in this, Emulator is not detecting the 320 density and it is not replacing those images under drawable-xhdpi folder.  But finally the problem is resolved if we create a folder with name drawable-hdpi-v8 for Android 2.2 (API Ver 8) it is working fine.. Anyway  @hackbod helped me lot to understant this functionality. Thanks a lot..